# How do I combine two queries together in SQL

Tags: sql, databricks

I need help figuring out how to write two queries in the same query.

I have created a table "tempview"  with the following columns:

```
ApplicationNum | MonthYear | TotalFinancedAmount
```

I wrote two queries to calculate to calculate the most and least amounts financed:
To calculate the most financed:

```
SELECT MonthYear, SUM(TotalFinancedAmount) AS TotalFinanced
FROM tempview
GROUP BY MonthYear
Order By Total Financed DESC LIMIT 1:
```

The other query to calculate the minimum is identical but instead of `DESC` I am using `ASC`
How could I write a query that does both together.

I am using databricks.

Comment: What's the expected result if two different MonthYear have the same max (or min) TotalFinanced amount?

Comment: Syntax varies by dbms AND version. Please update question tags to indicate which one you're using - and which version

Comment: To combine the results of two queries, you can use [UNION ALL](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union_all.php)

Comment: Every month will always have a different min and max. Union ALL sadly did not work, the min and max should be in separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following query  joining both queries results in the same row if this what you want :

```
SELECT   min_monthyear, min_total , max_monthyear , max_total 
 from (SELECT MonthYear as min_monthyear , SUM(TotalFinancedAmount) AS min_total
FROM tempview
GROUP BY MonthYear
Order By min_total ASC LIMIT 1) min_table , 
(SELECT MonthYear as max_monthyear , SUM(TotalFinancedAmount) AS max_total
FROM tempview
GROUP BY MonthYear
Order By max_total DESC LIMIT 1) max_table;
```